# How to use a component inside another

Tags: angular, typescript

I cannot use `app.module` as this is a large application. The component I want to use this component in DOES NOT HAVE a module file.

I have tried importing it and using `@Ngmodule` but doesn't work.

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: 'x' is not a known element:

Comment: Either your component has it own module and import that child module to it's parent module or You need to have the other component declared in the declarations array of your parent`@NgModule` and then use the `selector` of that component and use it inside any other component

Comment: ive declared @NgModule({declarations: [NameOfClassToImport]}) in the parent still can't find the element

Comment: if you're using parent and child module. In child module, you need to export your component in order to use it in the parent module

Comment: Nah the parent doesn't have a module i'm trying to use the component directly in the parent without creating two new module files.

Comment: Do you have `export class NameOfClassToImport {}` in your child component

Comment: Yes i'm exporting the class.

Comment: Have you used like `<child-component></child-component>` in your `parent.component.html` ?

Comment: Yep copied pasted the selector

Comment: Try to recreate the same in a Stackblitz demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is too big it's better to make different modules for features. As an example you can make an `auth module` and add your login and register components there. You have to declare your components which are belong to each module, within that child module. For that module, you can add a separate routing file as well. If you want to use one of your component's selector as , you need to export it in your child module. Don't forget to import `CommonModule` in your child module.

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
 BreadcrumbsComponent,
 ModalLoginComponent,
],
imports: [
 CommonModule,
 RouterModule,
 FormsModule,
 NgxSpinnerModule
],
exports: [
 BreadcrumbsComponent,
 ModalLoginComponent
]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

And in your `app.module`you have to import your child module.

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
 AppComponent,
 WorldWideComponent,
 HeaderComponent,
 FooterComponent,
 PageNotFoundComponent
],
imports: [
 BrowserModule,
 BrowserAnimationsModule,
 AppRoutesModule,
 SharedModule,
 CoreModule,
 UserModule,
 NgbModule
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't put a component in directives

You register it in `@NgModule` declarations:

```
@NgModule({
imports: [ BrowserModule ],
declarations: [ App , MyChildComponent ],
bootstrap: [ App ]
})
```

and then You just put it in the Parent's Template HTML as : `<my-child></my-child>`

Comment: I haven't been. Ive been declaring the module in the parent but it still can't be found.@NgModule({declarations: [NameOfClassToImport]})

Comment: 1

Don't declare a class that's already declared in another module.

Comment: then used lazy loading concept